# Use of whereinsoever

Tags: archaic-language, definition

Searching for the definition of wherein, i found the word **[whereinsoever](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whereinsoever)**.

I have however not found any clear definition and example of its use, could someome explain it to me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Whereinsoever** -

Parts of Speech - Adverb

Definition - In whatever place, point or respect.

Example Sentence -

> 1. Food must be mixed and incorporated with the digestive humor, power, and faculty of the stomach, **whereinsoever** it consists, or it will not nourish.
> 2. Howbeit **whereinsoever** any is bold, I speak foolishly, I am bold also.
> 3. For each is called to exercise this mercy towards his neighbour, **whereinsoever** the latter may have need of it; not only as regards the giving of earthly goods, but also the bearing with his neighbour's faults in all gentleness and mercy.

Note - This word seems to be pretty archaic.

Comment: The OED does categorize the word as "archaic", defining it as "In whatever matter, respect, etc.". There is an interesting use in 1526 where the word is split in two, "Wherin soever eny man dare be bolde.. I dare be bolde also" (*Bible* (Tyndale) 2 Cor. xi. 21). The most recently cited quote is from 1870, for what it's worth.